# How to switch to another page with xamarin for visual studio?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I was wondering whats the best way to switch to another page while programming with c# with mono for android programming? (eg. " having a menu lead to the actual activity when u press a button")... The code and some examples would be very helpful, thanks you. (im using linear layout by the way)

Comment: If you are looking to switch between the activities, you can look into the docs by Xamarin http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_an_activity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [xamarin doc](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,_multi-screen_applications):

```cs
var showSecond = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.showSecond);
showSecond.Click += (sender, e) => {
    StartActivity (typeof(SecondActivity));
};
```

`StartActivity(Type activityType)` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but I ran into another problem. I made a new class and a new xml, but the problem is (both) of my classes can only get id's from the first xml, the second xml I made id doesnt get detected... im pretty sure that i have it in the resource_layout file

Comment: Xamarin does not recognize xml files. it is axml. Btw you are trying to skip the tutorials. Get your hands out and go http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes

Comment: Read the tutorials, reproduce them. Then rinse, and repeat.